# Function Recursion in R

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function (NextWordPrediction) in R to predict the next word given some words. The basic structure is as follows:

1. If input exists in dat such that `nrow(dat) != 0` return input and answer
2. If input doesn't exist such that `nrow(dat) == 0` call to recursion and atempt input-1 (eg. if input is "hello great world" try "great world" so on and so forth until nrow `nrow(dat) != 0`
3. If after step 2 `nrow(dat) == 0` return string `"Word not in dictionary. We added this to our database!"` and add original input to dataset

Here is the full code:

```
NextWordPrediction <- function(input) {
        dat <- training %>%
                filter(., N_gram == str_count(input, "\\S+") + 1) %>%
                filter(grepl(paste("^", tolower(str_squish(input)), sep = ""), Word)) %>%
                arrange(., desc(Prop))
        
        if (nrow(dat) != 0) {
                assign("training",
                       training %>%
                               mutate(Frequency = ifelse(Word == input &
                                                                 N_gram == str_count(input, "\\S+"),
                                                         Frequency + 1,
                                                         Frequency)) %>%
                               group_by(., N_gram) %>%
                               mutate(., Prop = Frequency/ sum(Frequency)) %>%
                               data.frame(.),
                       envir = .GlobalEnv)
                
                val <- dat$Word_to_Predict[1]
                ans <- paste(str_squish(input), val)
                
                return(list(ans, head(dat,5)))
                
        } else if (nrow(dat) == 0 & word(input, 1) != "NA") {
                input_1 <-  Reduce(paste, word(input, 2:str_count(input,"\\S+")))
                
                return(NextWordPrediction(input_1)) 
                
        } else if (nrow(dat) == 0 & word(input, 1) == "NA") {
                assign("training",
                       training %>%
                               add_row(., Word = tolower(input), Frequency = 1, N_gram = str_count(input, "\\S+")),
                       envir = .GlobalEnv)
                ans <- paste("Word not in dictionary. We added this to our database!")
                return(ans)
        }
}
```

The issue I'm having happens somewhere between step 2 and 3. If input is not found after the recursion call, the added input to the database is input-1 ("great world") where I'd like the original input ("hello great world"). This is my first attempt to implement recursion and would like to understand the mistake in my code.

Thanks :)

---

**Update to be Reproducible:**

```
library(dplyr); library(stringr)

training <- data.frame(Word = c("hello", "she was great", "this is", "long time ago in"), Frequency = c(4, 3, 10, 1),
                       N_gram = c(1, 3, 2, 4), Prop = c(4/18, 3/18, 10/18, 1/18), Word_to_Predict = c(NA, "great", "is", "in"))

NextWordPrediction("she was") ## returns "she was" & "great"

NextWordPrediction("hours ago") ## returns "hours ago" & "in"

NextWordPrediction("words not in data") ## returns "Word not in dictionary. We added this to our database!" after trying "not in data", "in data" and adds "words not in data" to dataset
```

Comment: concatenate (`paste`) the removed word to the return value from your recursive call. This means you need to store the first word, recurse on the remaining words, then concatenate word1 again before returning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an imperfect and overly-complicated demonstration of a recursive function operating on strings. Ideally there are some more safeguards that could be put into place, and there are of course much faster, more efficient, smarter ways of doing this one task, but ... perhaps you'll get the point.

I'm going to change all `e`s to `a`s, one word at a time.

```r
e_to_a <- function(strings) {
  # unnecessarily complex
  message("# Called  : ", sQuote(strings))
  if (!nzchar(strings)) return(strings)
  word1 <- sub("^([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]?.*", "\\1", strings)
  others <- sub("^[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]?", "", strings)
  message("# - word1 : ", sQuote(word1))
  message("# - others: ", sQuote(others))
  # operate on the first word
  word1 <- gsub("e", "a", word1)
  if (nzchar(others)) {
    others <- e_to_a(others)
    return(paste(word1, others))
  } else {
    return(word1)
  }
}
```

In action:

```
e_to_a("hello great world")
# # Called  : 'hello great world'
# # - word1 : 'hello'
# # - others: 'great world'
# # Called  : 'great world'
# # - word1 : 'great'
# # - others: 'world'
# # Called  : 'world'
# # - word1 : 'world'
# # - others: ''
# [1] "hallo graat world"
```

The key is that when you make the recursive call, what you're currently doing

```r
return(NextWordPrediction(input_1))
```

is going to return *just* the recursive part, dismissing the first word. That would be analogous to me doing

```r
  if (nzchar(others)) {
    others <- e_to_a(others)
    # return(paste(word1, others))
    return(others)
  } else {
    return(word1)
  }
```

I hope you can apply this to your function.

---

Bottom line, since your question is not reproducible, I'll guess that your fix is something like:

```r
        } else if (nrow(dat) == 0 & word(input, 1) != "NA") {
                input_vec <- str_split(input, "\\s+")
                input_firstword <- input_vec[1]
                input_otherwords <- paste(input_vec[-1], collapse = " ")
                return(paste(input_firstword, NextWordPrediction(input_otherwords)))
                
        } else if (nrow(dat) == 0 & word(input, 1) == "NA") {
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand enough to apply this to my function

Comment: See my edit. If that doesn't work, then I suggest you make your question a bit more reproducible, including *small*, sample data (`training`), and listing all non-base packages you're using. My premise stands, though: you are intentionally discarding the first word and returning the rest, you need to somehow preserve that first word.

Comment: updated to be reproducible. I tried your edit and to implement your premise but I'm not able to. I understand now what the issue is but I can't formulate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stream-of-consciousness answer. It doesn't solve anything, but it highlights some areas where code can or must be changed. Up front: `== NA` fails; you're always discarding the first word in recursion; `NA` (the object meaning "could be anything") is being coerced into `"NA"`, the literal string.

1. Starting with a fresh `training`, I'll `debug(NextWordPrediction)` and trace line-by-line. It gets to `input_1 <- ...`, the first thing I notice is:

   - first time, `input_1` is `"great world"`;
   - next time, it is `"world"`;
   - next time, it is `"na world"`, **fail**.

   This is a classic fail on two counts:

   - the code assumes that there are multiple words, even though `str_count(input,"\\S+")` returns `1` here; and
   - it is a common mistake to assume that `2:...` is always increasing and will not go over a certain count, but unfortunately `2:1` returns `c(2L, 1L)` ... perhaps you should check the length of your vectors before arbitrarily counting past them.

   I *think* you're trying to guard against this with your previous test of `word(input,1) != NA` (which is also a mistake), but the only time that's going to happen is when `input` is 0-length vector (`character(0)`), not empty-string `""`. You won't get that with the current code, and I think your intent is for it to reduce to `""`.

   I'm going to change your `word(input, 2:str_count(...))` to

   ```r
   input_1 <- sub("^\\S*\\s?", "", input)
   ```
2. You have `word(input, 1) != "NA"` (and `==`), that is either mistaking R's native object for a string, or you think you should be checking for a literal string `"NA"`; granted, english doesn't use that much as a real word, some languages do. I'm not certain if you intend that to be the `NA` literal or if for some reason your function will convert `NA` to `"NA"` and you want to guard against that.

   That last assumption is fixing a symptom, not a problem. Never allow your function to return `"NA"` (this happens here in a couple of places), you need to guard against it. To me, it is perfectly reasonable to see a *word* `"NA"` and differentiate it from the R native `NA`. Data missingness is important to differentiate.
3. Assuming you meant `!= NA` instead ... `word(input, 1) != NA` will never work. Let's run through some examples:

   ```r
   word("hello", 1)
   # [1] "hello"
   word("", 1)
   # [1] ""
   word(c(), 1)
   # Warning in rep(string, length.out = n) :
   #   'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL
   # Error in mapply(function(word, loc) word[loc, "start"], words, start) : 
   #   zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length
   word(character(0), 1)
   # [1] NA
   ```

   Okay, so it *can* return an `NA`, when the input vector is a 0-length character vector, but ...

   ```r
   word(character(0), 1) == NA
   # [1] NA
   word(character(0), 1) == NA_character_
   # [1] NA
   ```

   That's right, you cannot check for `NA`-ness that way. (Did you know that there are over six kinds of `NA`? They are not the same, `identical(NA, NA_real_)`.)

   Use `is.na(.)`:

   ```r
   is.na(word(character(0), 1))
   # [1] TRUE
   ```

   (That's assuming we can see it in normal operation.)

   I'm going to change that `if` condition to:

   ```r
   } else if (nrow(dat) == 0 && nzchar(input) && !is.na(word(input, 1))) {
   ```
4. We're getting closer. Now I can get into the third call of the function, where `input` is finally `""` and we go into the first conditional block, assigning the new content to `training`. Unfortunately, `dat$Word_to_Predict[1]` is `NA`, so your `ans` is `" NA"`, which just doesn't seem logical. Granted, your default `training` dataset has this explicitly, and while I don't know what you mean to happen here, I suggest stringifying an R object of `NA` into `" NA"` seems wrong.

   I don't have a fundamental fix to this flow, though: you want to concatenate the `val` found with the previous `input` string, but ... if `Word_to_Predict` is `NA` (not a normal string), then ... what do you do? For the sake of moving forward, I'll dismiss concatenating `"NA"` onto a string ... though it's producing results that are "wrong" from a linguistic standpoint, I believe. (I'll just interpret `"NA"` as `"(I don't have a great value for this spot)"` or similar :-)
5. You are *always* `paste`ing a squished `input` with `val`, but ... if `input` is `""`, then `paste` still adds a space between them, which seems unnecessary. You can always "patch" this later by repeatedly squishing the strings, but ... symptom/problem again. I suggest instead using

   ```r
   ans <- str_squish(paste(input, val))
   ```
6. And my original point ...

   When you start with `"she was"`, it will find something on the first invocation, and we `paste` the `input` with the `val` to get the answer. However, when you have to go into recursion, you call the function again with the rest of the sentence and perfect discard the first word. For instance:

   ```r
   NextWordPrediction("hello great world")
   #1> `input` is "hello great world", second `if` block, `input_1` is "great world"
   #2> `input` is "great world", second `if` block, `input_1` is "world"
   #3> `input` is "world", second `if` block, `input_1` is `""`
   #4> `input` is "", first `if` block, `val` is `NA`, and `ans` is "NA"
   #3> blindly returns list("NA", head(dat)) (discarding "world")
   #2> blindly returns list("NA", head(dat)) (discarding "great")
   #1> blindly returns list("NA", head(dat)) (discarding "hello")
   ```

   Do you see the problem now? Instead of `return(NextWordPrediction(input_rest))`, you need to capture the result, prepend the word you stripped from `input`, and continue passing the updated return value up the chain. I suggest

   ```r
   input_1 <- gsub("\\s\\S*", "", input)
   input_rest <- sub("^\\S*\\s?", "", input)

   out <- NextWordPrediction(input_rest)
   out[[1]] <- str_squish(paste(input_1, out[[1]]))
   return(out)
   ```

---

After all of that, I now see

```r
NextWordPrediction("hello great world")
# [[1]]
# [1] "hello great world NA"
# [[2]]
#    Word Frequency N_gram Prop Word_to_Predict
# 1 hello         4      1    1            <NA>
```

which, according to your initial `training`, is correct.

**Unfortunately**, this breaks something else.

---

6. `"words not in data"` always eventually matches something (as will anything not in `training`), since it reduces to an empty string `""`, and your first logic of `grepl(paste("^", tolower(str_squish(input)), sep = ""), Word)` will always match something with `input` of `""`.

   We can fix this with a simple additional condition in your first filtering:

   ```r
     filter(nzchar(input) & grepl(paste("^", tolower(str_squish(input)), sep = ""), Word)) %>%
   ```
7. And finally, when you get to the final `if` block when you need to add data to `training`, if this is the first/outer call of the function, then `input` truly reflects the entire sentence, which is what you want. However, if you've done one or more calls of recursion, then `input` is merely one word in the chain, not the entire thing. And due to some of the assumptions above, at this stage `input` is `""`, so ... any addition would be useless.

   There are two strategies for dealing with this:

   1. Keep track of whether this is the outer (first) call or some inner call. When you recursively call, check the return value ... if empty and this is an inner call, return empty; if empty and this is the first/outer call, *then* append to `training`; or
   2. Always pass the entire string along with the current `input`. This would reverse my recommendation in bullet 6 above, so your second `if` block would just call `NextWordPrediction(input_rest, input_1)` (using my variables) and not `str_squish` after it. The squishing/pasting would be handled in the first `if` block, where you would need to prepend the value (if any) of `preceding`).

   ```r
   NextWordPrediction <- function(input, preceding = "") {
   ```

---

Side notes, not wrong per se but still not good.

- `&` (single) in an `if` condition *works* but is bad practice: `&` does vector logic, which means it can return vectors of length other than 1; `if` conditions must be length exactly 1, not 0 or 2 or more. Use `&&` here.
- `Reduce(paste, ...)` is just unnecessary. Use `paste(...)`.

Comment: thank you! I believe your answer gave me insight in solving my issue in a more simplistic way!

Answer (score 0):

After understanding the implications of recursion in my function thanks to @r2evans I realized that a solution by means of recursion would be too complicated and as a result the following code meets all my conditions and works as expected:

```
NextWordPrediction <- function(input) {
        dat <- training %>%
                filter(., N_gram == str_count(input, "\\S+") + 1) %>%
                filter(grepl(paste("^", tolower(str_squish(input)), sep = ""), Word)) %>%
                arrange(., desc(Prop))
        
        if (nrow(dat) != 0) {
                assign("training",
                       training %>%
                               mutate(Frequency = ifelse(Word == input &
                                                                 N_gram == str_count(input, "\\S+"),
                                                         Frequency + 1,
                                                         Frequency)) %>%
                               group_by(., N_gram) %>%
                               mutate(., Prop = Frequency/ sum(Frequency)) %>%
                               data.frame(.),
                       envir = .GlobalEnv)
                
                val <- dat$Word_to_Predict[1]
                ans <- paste(str_squish(input), val)
                
                return(list(ans, head(dat,5)))
                
        } else {
                for (i in 2:str_count(input, "\\S+")) {
                        input_1 <-  word(input, start = i, end =  str_count(input,"\\S+"))
                        
                        dat <- training %>%
                                filter(., N_gram == str_count(input_1, "\\S+") + 1) %>%
                                filter(grepl(paste("^", tolower(str_squish(input_1)), sep = ""), Word)) %>%
                                arrange(., desc(Prop))
                        if (nrow(dat) != 0) {
                                val <- dat$Word_to_Predict[1]
                                ans <- paste(str_squish(input), val)
                                
                                return(list(ans, head(dat,5)))
                                
                        } else if (nrow(dat) == 0 & i == str_count(input, "\\S+")) {
                                assign("training",
                                       training %>%
                                               add_row(., Word = tolower(input), Frequency = + 1, N_gram = str_count(input, "\\S+"), 
                                                       Word_to_Predict = word(input, -1)) %>%
                                               group_by(., N_gram) %>%
                                               mutate(., Prop = Frequency/ sum(Frequency)) %>%
                                               data.frame(.),
                                       envir = .GlobalEnv)
                                
                                ans <- paste("Word not in dictionary. We added this to our database!")
                                
                                return(ans)
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

It loops through input-1 until a value is found in the dataframe and when this happens an answer is returned, otherwise we add the original input to the dataframe.